# Silent remote notification to iOS from Google Cloud

Tags: ios, node.js, cloud, silent

To send a silent remote notification to my iOS app from Google Firebase Functions, this is my index.js file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp();
const messaging = admin.messaging();

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var payload = {
        "notification": {
            title: 'test title 2',
            body: 'test body 2.1',
            icon: 'https://i.pinimg.com/236x/2f/b9/bd/2fb9bd91b530d20410744249a418240b.jpg'
        }
        "data": {
               "aps" = {
        "content-available" : 1,
    };
        }
    }
    messaging.sendToTopic("backgroundUpdate", payload).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        res.send(response);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
        res.send(e)
    })
});
```

But Google keeps giving me this error message:

```
Deployment failure:
Build failed: /workspace/index.js:13 
"data": { ^^^^^^  SyntaxError: Unexpected string at new Script (vm.js:83:7) at checkScriptSyntax (internal/bootstrap/node.js:620:5) at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:280:11) at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3); Error ID: d984e68f
```

Can anyone point me to my error? I have not been able to find a solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like the payload you are sending its not a valid JSON, could it be the reason of the error?

Comment: Inside your payload variable, there are some errors. Replace `"aps" = {` with `"aps": {`, and remove the `;` right after `"content-available".